# parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase undefined

Tags: javascript, jsviews

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejJZc/6/) generates the following error using jsviews:

```
parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase is undefined
```

This is because tagName is undefined.

The fiddle represents the simplest possible case (using jsviews but not actually binding anything).  My actual application contains more complex templates, but they are all generating similar errors.

Rendering the same template with render instead of link works fine.

I doubt this is a bug - what am I missing in the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejJZc/13/

See here for how to use the JsViews `link()` method - and how it relates to the JsRender `render()` method:

http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvplaying

Comment: Thanks @BorisMoore.  I missed that little snippet, but I believe that solves my problem.  Is there a GitHub repository for the documentation that I might be able to contribute to?

Comment: The jsviews.com site, which has the documentation, is here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews.com. But in fact I create the documentation directly on the cloned site, by switching it into edit mode. It is built using JsViews (of course) and there is a 'secret' way of making it editable a bit like a Wiki. I'm afraid it is not currently set up for community editing though...